# How to drill into and out of nested divs that fill a main container with css3 and or JQuery

Tags: jquery, css

OK, here's my challenge:

I have a main DIV

```
<div class="container">

</div>
```

Inside that container are more divs... like so...and so on...

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="innerdiv">
         <div class="innerMostDiv"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="innerdiv">
         <div class="innerMostDiv"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="innerdiv">
         <div class="innerMostDiv"></div>
         <div class="innerMostDiv"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="innerdiv">
         <div class="innerMostDiv">
               ... and of course there could be more...hypothetically
         </div>
         <div class="innerMostDiv"></div>
         <div class="innerMostDiv"></div>
         <div class="innerMostDiv"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

So what I'm trying to do is that when you click on a DIV, it will EXPAND to fill the "container" class. And when you close it, it will come back to its original size.

Here's a infographic to show you what I'm trying to do.

[image]

I've seen something like this before, several years ago. You saw 6 boxes, click on one, it had 4 boxes, clicked on one of those, it expanded and there was another with blah, blah, blah, details. When you closed it, it's like, yes, the iPhone Drill into and out of grouping of icons. That's what I'm trying to achieve.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: drop your javascript here

Comment: Madalin, I would but I don't have it, yet. Forgive me, but actually what I want to emulate is a iPhone/Android Mobile App grouping where when you touch (in my case click) on a GROUP, (that has multiple inner apps(icons), it expands to show you more... then you click a group inside that parent, to drill into deeper until you get the information (or app for mobile) you want. In my case, all I'm trying to do is build a responsive, interactive, user centric dashboard.  Forgive me for the confusion.

Comment: Well, I've been doing a lot of research and thought about using MODALS as an option.  I've built a dynamic modal for a website I have which only has <div class="dynoModal"></div> and I populate it on the fly through JQUERY and JSON objects. Perhaps expanding on that theory would be cool. But I was really trying to see if anyone has seen a concept where CSS was used to expand simply colored boxes and as you drilled into them more they filled the main container, and as you backed out you saw the parent with the children inside... like in the infographic above.  But, the modal concept may work...